# Django Testing: no data in temporary database file

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-testing, django-database

I'm using a sqlite3 database set up as follows in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite',
        'NAME': 'path/to/config.sqlite',
        'TEST_NAME': 'path/to/test-config.sqlite',
        # ... USER, PASSWORD and PORT left out for brevity
    }
}
```

During a test run started with:

```
python manage.py test myapp.mytest
```

this temporarily creates a database file `path/to/test-config.sqlite` which I need in another application loaded with the required fixtures.

The database file however is empty, which I asserted during a pause in one test:

```
sqlite> select * from someapp_somemodel;

... no results here :(
```

Other test cases which do not require a sqlite file and for which the in-memory database suffices, no errors occurs.

My questions:

- Why doesn't django flush its data to the database file if it creates it anyway? and
- How can I convince django to do it, as I require the data to be dumped in the temporary database file?

**EDIT**

I'm using Django 1.3.1, if thats of any interest.

**EDIT2**

I'm familiar with fixtures, and I use them to populate the database, but my problem is that the data from the fixtures is not written to the database file during the test. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough on that fact.

**EDIT3**

As my question needs some clarification, please consider the following test setup (which is close to what I'm actually doing):

```
class SomeTestCase(django.test.TestCase):
    fixtures = ["some_fixture.json", "some_other_fixture.json"]

    def testSomething(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

When the `testSomething` method runs into the breakpoint I start up the `sqlite3` program and connect to the temporary database file created by Django. The fixtures are loaded (which I know, because other tests work aswell) but the data is not written to the temporary database file.

Comment: "which I asserted during a pause in one test" Which test is asserting? the Django test or your application loading the database? Can you clarify this a bit.

Comment: Django doesn't dump data from the "normal" database to the test database because that wouldn't make any sense. If tests use the database, they should probably expect the database in a minimal and fixed state. Now this "I use them [fixtures] to populate the database, but my problem is that the data from the fixtures is not written to the database file during the test." is **totally unclear**. Shouldn't the fixtures be loaded **before** running a tests ? Do you mean that you have to load the fixtures manually ? Can you elaborate on that and provide examples (runable code if possible).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What behaviour are you testing that actually needs a sqlite db file? Are you planning to go live using sqlite?

Comment: Is there a reason to use such an old version of django?

Comment: @jpic: No one is talking about the *normal* database here, my issue is only in the temporary database created during the tests and filled with the data taken from the fixtures specified. Yes, the fixtures *are* loaded before each test, but apparently they are not written to the *file*. I have updated my answer with a test case showing what I want to do.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling: In the background I have a map-drawing application which requires the vector data stored in the sqlite DB. *Going live* does not apply to our project, but it is required to be run with any DB backend system Django offers.

Comment: @Marcin: according to the Django page (https://www.djangoproject.com/), 1.3.1 is the current release version. Developing against the development version is not an option in my project.

Comment: @Constantinius: My apologies - that was posted in a moment of confusion. I agree that using the very latest release is entirely appropriate.

Comment: Are you sure that the database is **not written at all** ? It probably should be 0) written and then 1) deleted.

Comment: @jpic: The database file is created `test-config.sqlite` and is a valid sqlite file containing all my required tables. Only thing missing is the tables content. This file gets deleted once the last testcase has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way, but as I also messed with hdparm (with -F or -W 0/1), i don't know if it will work for you. I did reboot and re-try to make sure thought. Also, this test does **not** have SpatiaLite but as you said this is probably irrelevant.

Anyway, we need 2 screens to reproduce this, **screen0 runs the tests** and **screen1 is an sh shell** to work with will screen0's process is paused.

**Start the test** (screen0):

```
>>> ./manage.py test testapp
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'db_test.sqlite', or 'no' to cancel: yes
--Return--
None
> /home/jpic/testproject/testapp/tests.py(16)testSomething()
     14 
     15     def testSomething(self):
---> 16         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

**Check the size of the created test database file**, (screen1):

```
<<< 18:00.39 Mon Feb 20 2012!~/testproject 
<<< jpic@germaine!10004 env
>>> ls -l db_test.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 jpic jpic 49152 2012-02-20 18:00 db_test.sqlite
```

**Run PRAGMA SYNCHRONOUS sql command from python** (screen0):

```
ipdb> from django.db import connection; cursor = connection.cursor()
ipdb> cursor.execute("PRAGMA SYNCHRONOUS")
<django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.SQLiteCursorWrapper object at 0x294f348>
ipdb>
```

**Check if the size of the database file increased** (screen1):

```
<<< 18:00.42 Mon Feb 20 2012!~/testproject 
<<< jpic@germaine!10005 env
>>> ls -l db_test.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 jpic jpic 272384 2012-02-20 18:00 db_test.sqlite
```

**Data has been written to the file.**

It doesn't make much sense to me because apparently `PRAGMA SYNCHRONOUS` alone **[should just query for the value](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous)** (in my case: 2/FULL). But in practicee, it writes to disk. Note that if you haven't 2 (FULL) then you should set it to 2: `PRAGMA SYNCHRONOUS 2`.

Now, I can't say **what** was written (was it fully written ?) because I can't get my hands on the test database: if i run `sqlite db_test.sqlite` in screen1 to get a client on the test database: I can't run any command (nor a select, nor a .dump) because "SQL error: database is locked". But, I guess that's your problem now B)

Comment: I'm amazed, this works like a charm! On my box (maybe thats also because of `spatialite` instead of `sqlite`) I don't have any problems reading from the DB. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it has to do with [how Django tests use transactions](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8138)?

Check if the issue persists if you [turn off all transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#how-to-globally-deactivate-transaction-management) in settings.py:

```
DISABLE_TRANSACTION_MANAGEMENT = True
```

Comment: This is a nice hack, unfortunately it did not solve the issue. The database file is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

Have you run the initial syncdb to create the database tables?  (**python yourproject/manage.py syncdb**)

In your settings.py, what apps do you have installed under INSTALLED_APPS?

In your project, what models have you built?

Depending on what apps you have installed in INSTALLED_APPS and what custom models you have added to your project, will dictate what databases syncdb will create.

Comment: Adam: The `syncdb` command only influences the *live*/*normal* DB, not the one used for testing with `python manage.py test ...`. This command is regularly used in my project, but does not solve the issue described.

Answer (score 1):

From the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#the-test-database):

> ...When using the SQLite database engine the tests will by default use
>   an in-memory database (i.e., the database will be created in memory,
>   bypassing the filesystem entirely!). If you want to use a different
>   database name, specify `TEST_NAME` in the dictionary for any given
>   database in `DATABASES`.

Furthermore, if you [read about fixture loading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#fixture-loading):

> ...At the start of each test case, before `setUp()` is run, Django will flush the database, returning the database to the state it was in directly after syncdb was called...

If you need a fresh database with some fixtures loaded you can of course do so by creating an empty database with running `syncdb` and load some fixtures with [`django-admin.py loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture)!

Comment: lazerscience: I am aware of how django testing loads fixtures before the `setUp` method. My problem is that I need all the data from the fixtures for the test case be written to the *same* sqlite database file which I'm opening from the other application. I really don't want to be depending on a second prepopulated database.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your are doing something with **GeoDjango** based on your database engine, `'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite'`. GeoDjango needs extra setup and so my guess is it needs something extra for testing too. (If you aren't using GeoDjango just use `'django.db.backends.sqlite3'` as your database engine. Keep the `TEST_NAME` though otherwise Django will create the test DB in memory.)

There is a whole process for loading in the spatial data and the GeoDjango installation docs are very thorough. Here's a link direct to creating the [SpatiaLite database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/gis/install/#create-spatialite-db). You'll need to do basically the same thing for testing.

From the [testing docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/gis/testing/#spatialite):

> You will need to download the initialization SQL script for SpatiaLite:
>
> $ `wget http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/init_spatialite-2.3.zip`
>
> $ `unzip init_spatialite-2.3.zip`
>
> If **init_spatialite-2.3.sql** is in the same path as your project's manage.py, then all you have to do is:
>   `$ python manage.py test`

Comment: JCotton: You are right, I'm using `GeoDjango` with a spatialite database. I'm currently using the `SPATIALITE_SQL` option in `settings.py` to reference the `init_spatialite-2.3.sql`. Without it the testing procedure raises an exception when the database is set up.
I'm afraid, that using `spatialite` is not the core issue here, but thanks anyways.